# Most efficient way to store history of boolean values in C++ array

Tags: c++, arrays, optimization

Trying to find percentage of 'true' values at 1 minute intervals for 24hrs, so needing to keep track of 1440 booleans. Using a single bool array would mean almost 1.5KB - as memory is extremely limited wondering what the smallest way to acheive this might be. Below code is a 'rolling' single array method which seems to work in principle.

Was thinking to perhaps move hourly percentages to a new float array so combining sizes 60 and 24 arrays maybe, but any even more efficient method available?

```
float fPercentage(bool state)
{
  buffer_index = (buffer_index + 1) % WINDOW_SIZE; // Increment the buffer index
  mybuffer[buffer_index] = state; // Add the value to the rolling buffer
  int oldest_index = (buffer_index + 1) % WINDOW_SIZE;
  int count = mybuffer[buffer_index];
  for (int i = oldest_index; i != buffer_index; i = (i + 1) % WINDOW_SIZE) {
    if (mybuffer[i]) {
      count++;
    }
  }
  // Calculate the percentage of true Boolean values in the rolling buffer
  float percentage = ((float) count / (float) WINDOW_SIZE) * 100.0;

  // Output the percentage to the serial monitor
  Serial.print("Percentage of true values: ");
  Serial.print(percentage);
  Serial.println("%");
  return percentage;
}
```

Comment: for frequency you only need to count. Two integers: total and true, or true and false

Comment: the question is unclear. Is it 1 bool per minute and you need to find freq in 24 hours? Or is it many bool in 1 minute and you need freqs per minute? In either case you only need to store counters, not every single bool

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number That doesnʼt work for rolling data; you need to have the actual data to expire it.

Comment: I think `vector<bool>`, usually disliked because it doesnʼt work as expected, is actually good for you here: it stores each value as a single bit instead of a whole byte.

Comment: A `std::bitset` is another option.

Comment: "*needing to keep track of 1440 booleans. Using a single bool array would mean almost **1.5KB***" - sure, if you use a `bool[]` array where each `bool` is 1 byte each. That wastes 7 unused bits per `bool`. Instead, store 8 `bool` values together into a single byte in, say, a `uint8_t[]` array (or C++ equivalent), then you can squeeze it down to just **180 bytes**.